# Restricting access to sites

Tags: server, internet, squid, elinks

I'm having some problems configuring my local proxy server so that it would restrict access to certain websites.

The proxy server I'm using is Squid; I edited its configuration file found in `/etc/squid/squid.conf` to include the following:

```
acl wikipedia dstdomain .wikipedia.org
http_access deny wikipedia
```

I tried to redirect elinks to use Squid. According to Squid's config file, it listens to port 3128, so in `/etc/elinks/elinks.conf` I added the following:

```
set protocol.http.proxy.host = "localhost:3128"
```

I also restarted Squid with `sudo /etc/init.d/squid restart`, but I can still access the banned websites using Elinks. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Just for clarification, is that your entire configuration ? I can not tell what site you are trying to block and what url you entered into elinks. FWIW, IMO squid works well on a large LAN with several clients, but you need to maintain a blacklist. You can automate the process with SquidGuard. If you have a single client, try an alternate proxy such as privoxy or if you want a graphical option see http://askubuntu.com/questions/87568/how-to-block-deny-or-redirect-an-ip-address-or-website-domain/87606#87606 . You should also look at "transparent proxies"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I edited my examples. Yes, that is all the configuration I did. All I want is to block access to a site and its domains (in this case, Wikipedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your syntax is a bit off. Try

```
acl blacklist dstdomain .wikipedia.org
http_access deny blacklist
```

Other options are outlined here: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#How_do_I_implement_an_ACL_ban_list.3F

If you just want to block a single site, you can use `/etc/hosts`

```
0.0.0.0  wikipedia.org
```

Or iptables

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d wikipedia.org -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```