# Restricting access to yahoo.com with squid and elinks

Tags: squid, elinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restricting access to sites](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88343/restricting-access-to-sites)

I need to restrict the access to yahoo.com and fr.yahoo.com in elinks using squid. Can everyoane help me

Answer (score 1):

Two steps are required:
1) set up elinks to use proxy. You can do this by either exporting http_proxy env variable.

Ex.: `export http_proxy='http://[user[:password]@]your.proxy.server.com:8080'`

Other way - is to configure elinks to use your proxy server.

2) configure squid to to block requests to yahoo.com and fr.yahoo.com.
Ex.:

`squid.conf`:

```
acl blocked_yahoo dstdomain yahoo.com
acl blocked_yahoo dstdomain fr.yahoo.com
#or you can have rule for all subdomains:
#acl blocked_yahoo dstdomain .yahoo.com
http_access deny blocked_yahoo
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit with first step. Sorry but i am new with linux

Comment: There's environmental variables that can be used by programs. One good example is env var LANG which is used by programs to determine which translation to use. Same with http_proxy env var. So just run elinks with the following command: `http_proxy='http://username:password@your.proxy.server.com:3128' elinks` OR `export http_proxy='http://username:password@your.proxy.server.com:3128` and then run elinks from this console. Or add export http_proxy=.. to your ~/.bashrc
Other way is to run elinks and go to options manager -> protocols -> HTTP -> Proxy configuration and set proxy settings