# How to block ips similar to editing the HOSTS file on Windows

Tags: networking, windows-7, ip

I have recently switched to Ubuntu and need to block a few Ips for gaming. Previously, I could simply add a line to the file `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\HOSTS` but I am unsure how to do this on Ubuntu. How can I block these Ips on Ubuntu?

P.S. I am running Ubuntu on an external hard drive connected to the main computer with Windows.

Comment: this may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87568/how-to-block-deny-or-redirect-an-ip-address-or-website-domain

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu it works the same, only the file is located somewhere else.

The location in Ubuntu is `/etc/hosts`.

To edit this file you must be root (the administrator in Linux):

- GUI (Graphical User Interface)

  ```
  gksudo gedit /etc/hosts
  ```

  *`gksudo` starts a GUI application as `root` and `gedit` is the default GUI text editor in Ubuntu.*
- CLI (Command Line Interface)

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/hosts
  ```

  *`sudo` starts a CLI application as `root` and `nano` is the default CLI text editor in Ubuntu.*

The syntax of the `hosts` file is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```